# Pandas Dataframe csv to Sql with 'multi' method generate error

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, csv

I am moving a lot of data from local csv files into a Azure based SQL database. 
I am using sqlalchemy and ODBC Driver 17
Chunk size is 5,000.

Everything is fine if I don't switch on the multi method in the final DF to_sql.
The dataframe is a 9 column dataframe read from csv

the error message I got when switching on multi method is:
"('The SQL contains -20536 parameter markers, but 45000 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')"
The 45,000 is probably the 9 columns times the 5,000 chunck which makes sense.  But why does the SQL contains -20536 is giving me a big headache.

thanks so much. My code looks like:

```
import pyodbc
import urllib
from sqlalchemy import create_engine,Table,MetaData
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

params = urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=tcp:oac- 
data1.database.windows.net,1433;DATABASE=OAC Analytics;UID=xxxxxx;PWD=xxxxx")
chunk = 5000
engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params)
conn=engine.connect()
DF_DFS = pd.read_csv('xxxxx\Fact-Qikids-DFS.csv', header=0)
DF_DFS = DF_DFS[['Campus ID','Date','Age Group','Room #','Booking type','Absence','Attendances','Fees 
Charged','Version']]
DF_DFS.to_sql('QikKids-DFS-Parsed',con=conn,if_exists='append',index=False,chunksize = 
chunk,method='multi')
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out an alternative is to switch on fast_executemany

The only thing to watch out for is that it request index to be on